# App UI Change it's Position when Skype call started

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7-statusbar

My problem is UI of app not showing as it is when I started Skype call.
App move down little bit. that's why I can't see some text on tab.

I don't wan't this behaviour.
is it possible when Skype call started it override on app header?